# Trouble with bot.wait_for() Discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

So modern documentation on the bot.wait_for() coroutine is not super detailed, and I'm having trouble getting it to work with reactions. Would appreciate feedback.

Python 3 with Discord.py

```
## Test Role Add
@kelutralBot.command(name='testreaction')
async def testReaction(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    message = await ctx.send("This is a test message.")
    emojis = ['\u2642','\u2640','\u2716']
    for emoji in emojis:
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)

    def check(reaction, user):
            return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == '\u2642'

    try:
        reaction, user = await kelutral.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("Window has passed to self-assign pronouns. Please DM a mod if you would still like to do so.")
    else:
        print(reaction)
        male = get(member.guild.roles, name="He/Him")
        await member.add_roles(male)
        print("Assigned " + member.name + " He/Him pronouns.")
```

Comment: Do you need to use `kelutralBot.wait_for()`, not just `kelutral.wait_for()`?

Comment: It's client here, which is `kelutral`. `client.wait_for()`

Comment: You don't need both a bot and client, since you are using commands just the `Bot()` will do. Also, are you trying to add a role to the user that reacts to the male_sign emoji?

Answer (score 3):

Two things were wrong.

First, don't use `Client` and `Bot` in the same command. `Bot` is sufficient for both.

Second, Unicode Emoji for Discord are treated as `'\U000#####'`, which was the biggest problem.

Once we solved that, everything worked as intended.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are checking if the person who sent the reaction is the author of the message that contains the message, which is only satisfied by the bot that reacted. Also consider using a role ID instead (server settings > roles > left click role > right click role > copy ID). You also want to be consistent with `kelutral` or `kelutral Bot` throughout the command.

```py
@kelutralBot.command(name='testreaction')
async def testReaction(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    message = await ctx.send("This is a test message.")
    emojis = ['\u2642','\u2640','\u2716']
    for emoji in emojis:
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == member and str(reaction.emoji) == '\u2642' # check against the member who sent the command, not the author of the message

    try:
        reaction, user = await kelutralBot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("Window has passed to self-assign pronouns. Please DM a mod if you would still like to do so.")
    else:
        print(reaction)
        male = ctx.message.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID_GOES_HERE) # put your role ID here #
        await member.add_roles(male)
        print(f"Assigned {member.name} He/Him pronouns.")
```

Keep in mind your code only works for the "male" role, you have to implement a different check function to use it for everything.